# Solving a difference equation using z-transform

Tags: systems-of-equations, z-transform

Solve the difference equation

\begin{equation}
x_{n+1}-2x_n=n
\end{equation}

Solution:

I use the z-transform table:

\begin{equation}
     \begin{array}{cc}
         First \ term,  x_{n+1}:\\  Table\ entry:  x_{n+k}\rightarrow zX(z)-\sum_0^{k-1}x_jz^{1-j}= zX(z) \\
          Second\ term -2x_n: \\
Table\ entry: cx_n \rightarrow cX(z) =-2X(z)\\
Third\ term, n:\\
        Table\ entry:   n \rightarrow \frac{z}{(z-1)^2}
     \end{array}
 \end{equation}

Therefore the result is

\begin{equation}
     zX(z)-2X(z)=\frac{z}{(z-1)^2}
 \end{equation}
\begin{equation}
     X(z)=\frac{z}{(z-1)^2(z-2)}
 \end{equation}

Is this correct to the knowledge of keen readers?

UPDATE:

Pauls point is given below:

from inverse z-transform table acting on:

\begin{equation}
     X(z)=\frac{z}{(z-1)^2(z-2)} = \frac{1-2z}{(z-1)^2}+\frac{2}{z-2}
 \end{equation}

we have:

\begin{equation}
 \begin{array}
    f \frac{1-2z}{(z-1)^2}\rightarrow \frac{1}{(z-1)^2}-\frac{2z}{(z-1)^2}\\
     \rightarrow z^{-1}\frac{z}{(z-1)^2}-2
     \frac{z}{(z-1)^2} \rightarrow (n-1)\sigma_{n-1}-2n, \\
     \frac{1}{z-2}\rightarrow 2z^{-1}\frac{z}{z-2}\rightarrow 2^{n}
\end{array}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    x_n=(n-1)\sigma_{n-1}-2n+2^{n}
\end{equation}

Thanks

Comment: Yes, that is ok assuming $x_0 = 0$. You can now use partial fractions to re-write $X$ and use your table to find $x_n$.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I just added an update.

Comment: Note that $z^{-1}.\frac{z}{z-2}$ has transform ${2^{n-1}}={0,1,2,2^2,...}$ not $2^n$. It can be useful to do partial fractions on $\frac{X}{z}$ instead of $X$. When you are done multiply back by $z$ and you have terms in your table without needing to use a shift.

Comment: If you make your solution here, it will be more easy to understand what you mean. According to my Prof, the solution I made here is fine. But I am interested in learning your method too. About the $2^{n}$ I made a typo in the original respective partial fraction, it should be multiplied by 2. In fact, I am not sure why this become $2^n$. The rule says $\frac{2z}{z-2}=2\frac{z}{z-2}=2\cdot 2^n$. Here we have $\frac{2}{z-2}=\frac{2}{z}\frac{z}{z-2}=2z^{-1}2^n$. The formula of z-transform is $X(z)=\sum_0^\infty x_nz^{-n}$. Here $x_n=2^{n+1}$ and $z^{-n}$ is given where $n=-1$. Which rule?

Comment: You can't say $\frac{2}{z}\frac{z}{z-2}$ has transform $2z^{-1}2^n$ as that mixes up the sequence and its transform. If ${a_n}={a_0, a_1, ...}$ has transform $A(z)$ then ${a_{n-1}}$, which is defined to mean the delayed sequence ${0, a_0, a_1, ...}$ has transform $z^{-1}A(z)$.

Comment: Yes, you are right, that was bad terminology. What I mean is that it is an intermediate towards the transform, and using the right entry in the table. But the only entry I can find is $z^{-k}X(z)\rightarrow x_{n-k}\sigma_{n-k}=2^{n+1-1}\sigma_{n-1}$, but this is something else than $x_n=2^n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid delayed sequences in your solution by putting

$\frac{X(z)}{z}=\frac{1}{(z-1)^2(z-2)} =\frac{-1}{z-1} -\frac{1}{(z-1)^2}+\frac{1}{z-2}$

Then multiplying through by $z$

$X(z)=\frac{-z}{z-1} -\frac{z}{(z-1)^2}+\frac{z}{z-2}$

which are all in your table

Comment: Thanks for this. I will account for this approach too, it seems certainly easier.